# Visual C++: Exporting decorated function name in a def file

Tags: c++

I want to export a decorated function name in a def file like this:

```
LIBRARY Example
EXPORTS
??0__non_rtti_object@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z=myfunc @1
```

The Problem is that the linker strips the function name at the first @-sign and places just
"??0__non_rtti_object" into the export table. My question is now, if there is a way to include
the @-characters as well? I use Visual Studio 2010. Maybe there is someone who can help me.

Thanks in advance, Hannes.

Comment: I'm curious *why* you want to use the .DEF file the first place... Could you elaborate?... Why won't you use the `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)` qualifiers?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
The problem is that I need to have special names exported by a dll. I think the only way to give such names is to use a def file. The dllexport, dllimport qualifiers only export/import a function like it is named in the sourcecode. But I need to rename the functions. Another reason is, that you can't use @-signs in a C file, but export it like it is done when C++ functions are decorated.

@ymett

I already tried to use quotes, but it doesen't work. Did you get it to work? If so, what version do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by special names? Names with special characters like '@'? . . . Or if you just want to rename the function, what don't you wrap the desired function by another function with the name you want? . . . Do you want to remove the decoration (if yes, then use the `extern "C"` qualifier)? . . . Your aim is unclear... :-(

Comment: Yes, I mean special characters like '@'. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. However, I tried `?f@@YAHN@Z @2` for a function `int f(double)`, and it worked fine. What is the actual signature of your function?

Comment: I don't have a signature. I only want that a function is named `?f@@YAHN@Z` for example. That means other applications can import `?f@@YAHN@Z`.

Answer (score 3):

### Preamble

You didn't answer my comment about the use of the .DEF file, so I assume you must be unfamiliar with the the `dllexport` and `dllimport` qualifiers. With them, there is no need for the .DEF file to export symbols.

If there is a particular need for the .DEF file that invalidate the use of the `dllimport`/`dllexport` feature, please ignore the following.

### How to use `dllimport`/`dllexport`?

In your public header (say, `public.hpp`), write something like:

```
#ifdef MY_PROJECT_EXPORTS
   #define MY_PROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define MY_PROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

This way, the macro `MY_PROJECT_API` will enable the export/import of your symbols. For example, later, in the same `public.hpp`, you can declare:

```
// A global variable
MY_PROJECT_API int myGlobalVariable ;

// A function
MY_PROJECT_API void my_function() ;

// A class or struct
class MY_PROJECT_API MyClass
{
   public :
      int i;
      virtual int foo() ;
      // etc.
} ;
```

Then, what you need to do is, in the project options of your library, define the `MY_PROJECT_EXPORTS`: This way, when you compile your library, the symbols above are declared `dllexport`, and when someone else includes your `public.hpp` header, the symbols above will be `dllimport`

And if your code is cross-platform (`dllimport`/`dllexport` is a MS compiler feature), just wrap the defines above around a compiler test. For example:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
   // For MS Visual Studio
   #ifdef MY_PROJECT_EXPORTS
      #define MY_PROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
      #define MY_PROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
#else
   // For other compilers
   #define MY_PROJECT_API
#endif
```

### About the .DEF file?

The .DEF file was used *before*, when exportable C functions were still "the way to go" on Visual Studio.

For strong type safety, C++ decorate its symbols.

The downside is that each compiler has its own decoration scheme (which never bothered me in 12-years of development), and that finding the exact, decorated name of a symbol can't be painful.

But the merits of that is that:

1. You can now export overloaded/namespaced functions/symbols
2. the parameter types are part of the ABI, meaning the linker can verify you aren't screwing up or cheating with your types

The `dllimport` and `dllexport` features have the following advantages:

1. it enables the export to be done at source level, instead of using yet another project file
2. the programmer can now ignore the particular decoration scheme (which usually only interests the linker), all the while profiting from the strong type safety of C++ extended to the linker.

### Sources

For more information, see:

- `__declspec` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx
- `dllexport`, `dllimport` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx
- Using `dllimport` and `dllexport` in C++ Classes : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx