# Solving LNK4022 (not a unique symbol "Initialize" found) without changing export.def

Tags: c++, dll, libtorch

I am trying to solve an LNK4022 issue (not a unique symbol "Initialize" found) but I can't modify the export.def file. The release is a DLL which can only be read by the final software if the export file is respected.

Also my DLL is using the libtorch librairy and I can't modify it either.

```
1>Export.def : warning LNK4022: impossible de trouver une correspondance unique pour le symbole 'Initialize' 
1>Export.def : warning LNK4002: "struct softwareInstanceDetails * __cdecl Initialize(struct softwareEnvironment *,struct MyLocalsoftwareData)" (?Initialize@@YAPEAUsoftwareInstanceDetails@@PEAUsoftwareEnvironment@@UMyLocalsoftwareData@@@Z) défini(e) dans x64\Release\software.obj 
1>Export.def : warning LNK4002: "public: void __cdecl torch::jit::tensorexpr::BlockCodeGen::Initialize(void)" (?Initialize@BlockCodeGen@tensorexpr@jit@torch@@QEAAXXZ) défini(e) dans D:\libtorch\lib\torch_cpu.lib 1>Export.def : warning LNK4002: "public: void __cdecl c10::uint128::Initialize(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?Initialize@uint128@c10@@QEAAX_K0@Z) défini(e) dans D:\libtorch\lib\c10.lib 
1>Export.def : error LNK2001: symbole externe non résolu Initialize
```

I tried to add extern 'C' in front of the function to avoid to modify the export file and because I though it would add the mangled name of the function during compilation. It didn't work.

Is there anyone who faced and solved this issue before?

Thank you in advance,

Laurick

Comment: You could put `Initialize=?Initialize@@YAPEAUsoftwareInstanceDetails@@PEAUsoftwareEnvironment@@UMyLocalsoftwareData@@@Z` into the DEF file, to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: I did but then the final software can't read the compiled DLL

Comment: What does it complain about? With this line, the exported symbol should be `Initialize` (you could check that with [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/). Is that not what the "final software" expects?

Comment: To check your proposition, I deleted libtorch from the DLL and I compiled twice either with "Initialize=?Initialize@@YAPEAUsoftwareInstanceDetails@@PEAUsoftwareEnvironment@@UMyLocalsoftwareData@@@Z" and with "Initialize" only. It is not working with " Initialize=?Initialize@@YAPEAUsoftwareInstanceDetails@@PEAUsoftwareEnvironment@@UMyLocalsoftwareData@@@Z" and it is working with "Initialize"

Comment: What does Dependency Walker or dumpbin show for the DLL that works, and for the DLL that doesn't? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Dependency Walker shows that "Initialize=?Initialize@@YAPEAUsoftwareInstanceDetails@@PEAUsoftwareEnvironment@@UMyLocalsoftwareData@" is not connected (red color) whereas everything else is connected (green color). I just noticed with it that it is seen in c++ but the rest is in c

Comment: Ah. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15907458). The `@` sign has special meaning in the DEF file, so mangled names containing it don't work.

Comment: I wonder - can you declare your `Initialize` function as `extern "C"`? Then it would be mangled as just `_Initialize`, and that you can specify in the DEF file.

Comment: yes it worked ;) However I just found out the final c-software can't read libtorch which is written in c++. So I am trying to use C binding/wrapper with libtorch