# MS Visual C++: Exporting a symbol with an `@`

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, name-mangling

I've been trying to export a function as symbol that contains an `@` in it using both a DEF file or a `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:NEW_NAME=OLD_NAME")`, but unfortunately it seems that when using a DEF-file the `@` is interpreted as to give the ordinal.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:foo@bar=foo")
void foo() { }
```

When I run the resulting binary through `dumpbin /exports` I get:

```
ordinal hint RVA     name
      1    0 00001000 foo = foo (...)
```

This seems related but the actual question has never been answered:
[Visual C++: Exporting decorated function name in a def file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413242/visual-c-exporting-decorated-function-name-in-a-def-file)

---

## Background info

The actual goal is actually to provide a function **F** (here `foo()`) under an alternative, `__stdcall`-decorated, name **S** (here `foo@bar`).  The problem being an old library **L1** I do not have source-code access too needing this symbol **S** which is technically still provided but as the function **F**.  Implementing **S** and then chain-calling **F** is non-trivial since I'd need to call **F** from within **S** but in the header of **F** there exists a function **S** but it's not exported anymore, so when compiling I'd have a clashing definition.

The best thing would be to just create an alias from **S** to **F**.

Comment: I couldn't understand anything from the background info...

Comment: @OfekShilon It's not really vital to the question. Thing is: You have a library with a function which in earlier days was exported as Symbol S but nowadays as Symbol S'. You cannot implement a function s.t. it's symbol is S' that calls S since the function name of both symbols is the same.